# jQuery counter + each reset

Tags: jquery

I'm using the code below to move images in a pair of sliders, but the first slider is jumping an extra step before resetting. 
slider 1 = 5 images, 
slider 2 = 6 images

```
function summarySlider(count) {
  var itemWidth = '20.2';
  var itemList = $('.summary-item-list');
  $(itemList).css('transform', 'translateX(-'+ (itemWidth * count) +'%)');
}
$(window).on("load", function () {
  $('.summary-v2-block').each(function(index){
    var count = 0;
    var limit = $(this).find('.summary-item').length;
    setInterval(function() {
      if (count === limit) {
        count = 0;
      }
      console.log(index, limit,  count);
      summarySlider(count);
      count++;
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

I think what is going on is that index 0 is actually the second slider, and index 1 is the first slider. It's counting indexes backwards?
How can I make index 0 the first slider?

This is the console output
(index, limit,  count)

0 5 0

1 6 0

0 5 1

1 6 1

0 5 2

1 6 2

0 5 3

1 6 3

0 5 4

1 6 4

0 5 0

1 6 5

0 5 1

1 6 0

Comment: Because image counts are not equal? You said 1st has 5 images and 2nd one has 6 right? That means while 1st one reaches its end, 2nd one still has one more to go

Comment: sorry - but I am not seeing the issue - one slide is showing from 050 to 054 (which is expected cos it has 5 images) and the other one shows from 160 to 165 (which makes sense for a slide with 6 images. it seems to show what i would expect with the 5 image slider cycling with 5 images and the other with 6. but its late so i might be missing something

Comment: @gavgrif I know right, I've spent too long looking at this too. But like the first slider has length 5, which is correct, but I think the first slider is getting assigned index 1. and the Second slider is index 0. So one slider is finishing early, the other is resetting one late

Comment: `var itemList = $('.summary-item-list');` is not instance specific

Comment: @charlietfl what does that mean?

Comment: It means the count passed to `summarySlider()` from one slider instance will affect both instances of those elements

Comment: @charlietfl YES! You probably saved me hours, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the timing but rather that your `summarySlider` function is looking for and manipulating elements that exist in both sliders.

You could pass in another argument for the parent slider element and use `find()` to make it instance specific

```
function summarySlider($slider, count) {
  var itemWidth = '20.2';
  var itemList = $slider.find('.summary-item-list');
  $(itemList).css('transform', 'translateX(-'+ (itemWidth * count) +'%)');
}
$(window).on("load", function () {
  $('.summary-v2-block').each(function(index){
    var count = 0;

    var $slider=$(this);// to pass to `summarySlider()`

    var limit = $(this).find('.summary-item').length;
    setInterval(function() {
      if (count === limit) {
        count = 0;
      }
      console.log(index, limit,  count);
      summarySlider($slider, count);
      count++;
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```